# JS onloadedmetadata does not fire on ANDROID CHROME when the phone is using mobile data

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I have a mobile application that has a feature that needs to fetch some metadata from a video such as the duration. However, something strange is happening:

When I my phone is connected to a wifi network, everything works fine. But, when my phone is using the mobile data (4G) the event handler `onloadedmetadata` does not fire.

I already tried to debug the application with remote developer tools and I could not understand the problem. It just don't fire the event.

For the registry, I am using Chrome browser with the latest version `50.0.2661`

You can check an example here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onloadedmetadata

Do you have any idea of what can be happening here?

Thansk a lot

Comment: Did you find a solution?